# Detect when new FCM token generated from outside the service

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to clean the firebase token when the user sign out and need to stop him from getting push notifications from the backend.
What I have done so far is,
I have created the firebase service and I am controlling the automatic token generation by the following code 
In Manifest,

```
<!-- FCM: Disable auto-init -->
    <meta-data android:name="firebase_messaging_auto_init_enabled"
        android:value="false" />
    <meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled"
        android:value="false" />
```

In the log out Activity,

```
 Thread {
         try {
           FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId()
           FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().isAutoInitEnabled = true
           FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().isAutoInitEnabled = false
         } catch (e: IOException) {
           e.printStackTrace()
         }
       }.start()
```

and I'm getting the new token in the Login Activity by below code,

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId.addOnSuccessListener {
            devicePushToken = it.token
            sharedPreferences.setValue(Constant.FCM_PUSH, devicePushToken)
            Log.e(TAG + '2', it?.token.toString())
        }
```

But the problem is, it returns the deleted old FCM token. The new token generation takes some time. It is generated correctly in the service OnNewToken method but I couldn't find a way to get the new token using a callback from the service to the Login Activity.And also If I wait some time and request again using the above(FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId.addOnSuccessListener) method It returns the correct token

Comment: Actually you want new TOKEN id then in thread to received new TOKEN id. Like AsyncClass

Comment: Yeah, The problem is it takes some time to receive the new token. Until that the getInstanceId method returns the expired token. The problem is If the user signs in again before the new token generates he won't receive notifications..

Comment: As per my knowledge its not expire token.Per device unique token id.So its better to re-generate token before login.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer for this question myself, 
So I'm going to post it here for anyone who faced this issue like me...

I have used rxJava observable to achieve this
First, you need to add an observable in the firebase service

```
companion object{
    private var tokenData: PublishSubject<String> = PublishSubject.create()

    fun getObservable(): PublishSubject<String> {
        return tokenData
    }
}
```

And the in onNewToken method you can set the observerble value when new token is generated,

```
override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
    super.onNewToken(token)
    tokenData.onNext(token)
}
```

Then you can get the newly generated token once it's generated by the following method,

```
val tokenObservable: Observable<String> =PushNotificationService.getObservable()    
val tokenSubscriber = object: io.reactivex.Observer<String> {
            override fun onNext(token: String) {
                println("**********$token")
                sharedPreferences.setValue(Constant.FCM_PUSH, token)
                activity?.setResult(RequestCodes.RESULT_NAV_LOGOUT).also {
                    activity?.finish()
                }
                hideProgress()//Display a progressbar so that user can wait untill new token is generated and hide it here on success

            }

            override fun onComplete() {
                println("onComplete")

            }

            override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                activity?.setResult(RequestCodes.RESULT_NAV_LOGOUT).also {
                    activity?.finish()
                }
                hideProgress()
            }

            override fun onSubscribe(s: Disposable) {
                println("onSubscribe")
            }
        }

        tokenObservable.subscribe(tokenSubscriber)
```

Answer (score 0):

in java you can achieve this by the following code. From any activity/fragment you can call it.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId();

                FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Log.w(TAG, "getInstanceId failed", task.getException());
                                    return;
                                }

                                // Get new Instance ID token
                                String token = task.getResult().getToken();

                                // Log and toast
                                Log.d(TAG, token);

                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, token, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    }).start();
```